# Clicking the button adds “undefined” instead of item

Tags: javascript, html

I just want my item to be added to the list.

I have tried putting `"constant value"` instead of `candidate.value`; then the value is getting displayed.

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="candidate" />
  <button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
  <button onclick="removeItem()">remove item</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addItem() {
      var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
      var li = document.createElement("li");

      li.setAttribute('id', candidate.value);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    function removeItem() {
      var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
      var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);

      ul.removeChild(item);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

The item should be added by clicking the “add item” button, but it is getting added as `undefined`.

Here’s a screenshot of the IDE:

[image]

Comment: I tried this on my own and it works. You will get an error when you try to remove an item which doesn't exist with the given id. Also it's possible to add an empty element.

Comment: Your code works as expected in Chrome 78. What web browser do you use ?

Comment: Why would you [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58792787/revisions) the only thing that makes your problem reproducible and make your question [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4642212)?

Comment: chrome 7.8 only

Comment: @akashpatil You mean Chrome 78? My guess is that you have duplicate IDs (e.g. `id="candidate"`). Try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser to find out what `candidate` is. Your question does not contain a [mre].

Comment: sry @SebastianSimon this i my first ques but i will make sure this will not happen in upcoming ques.

Comment: by mistake i used same id that's y i was getting undefined values all the time